# SQL Inner Join based on MAX of timestamp

Tags: sql, sqlite, max, inner-join, where-clause

**Amended Once**

**Amended Twice: The headers of the remaining 9 tables except for reports are always called "what".**

I have about 10 tables with the following structure:

```
reports (165k rows)
+-----------+-----------+
| identifier| category  | 
+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | fixed     |
| 2         | wontfix   |
| 3         | fixed     |
| 4         | invalid   | 
| 5         | later     | 
| 6         | wontfix   | 
| 7         | duplicate | 
| 8         | later     | 
| 9         | wontfix   | 
+-----------+-----------+   
 status (300k rows, all identifiers from reports come up at least once)
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| identifier| time      | what     |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 1         | 12        | RESOLVED |
| 1         | 9         | NEW      |
| 2         | 7         | ASSIGNED |
| 3         | 10        | RESOLVED |
| 5         | 4         | REOPEN   |
| 7         | 9         | ASSIGNED |
| 4         | 9         | ASSIGNED |
| 7         | 11        | RESOLVED |
| 8         | 3         | NEW      |
| 4         | 3         | NEW      |
| 7         | 6         | NEW      |
+-----------+-----------+----------+

 priority (300k rows, all identifiers from reports come up at least once)
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| identifier| time      | what     |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 3         | 12        | LOW      |
| 1         | 9         | LOW      |
| 9         | 2         | HIGH     |
| 8         | 7         | HIGH     |
| 3         | 10        | HIGH     |
| 5         | 4         | MEDIUM   |
| 4         | 9         | MEDIUM   |
| 4         | 3         | LOW      |
| 7         | 9         | LOW      |
| 7         | 11        | HIGH     |
| 8         | 3         | LOW      |
| 6         | 12        | MEDIUM   |
| 7         | 6         | LOW      |
| 6         | 9         | HIGH     |
| 2         | 6         | HIGH     |
| 2         | 1         | LOW      |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

What I need is:

```
 reportsfinal (165k rows)
+-----------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| identifier| category  | what11       |  what22    |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| 1         | fixed     | RESOLVED     | LOW        |
| 2         | wontfix   | ASSIGNED     | HIGH       |
| 3         | fixed     | RESOLVED     | LOW        |
| 4         | invalid   | ASSIGNED     | MEDIUM     |
| 5         | later     | REOPEN       | MEDIUM     |
| 6         | wontfix   |              | MEDIUM     |
| 7         | duplicate | RESOLVED     | HIGH       |
| 8         | later     | NEW          | HIGH       |
| 9         | wontifx   |              | HIGH       |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+------------+
```

That is, `reports` (after query = `reportsfinal`) serves as the basis table and I have to add one or two columns from 9 other tables. The `identifier` is the key, but in some tables, the `identifier` comes up multiple times. In these cases I want to use the entry with the highest time only.
I tried several queries, but none of them worked. If possible, I want to run one query to get different columns from the 9 other tables with this approach.

What I tried based on the answer below:

```js
select  T.identifier,
        T.category,
        t.what AS what11,
        t.what AS what22 from (
     select R.identifier,
     R.category,
     COALESCE(S.what,'NA')what,
     COALESCE(P.what,'NA')what,
     ROW_NUMBER()OVER(partition by R.identifier,R.category ORDER by (select null))RN
     from reports R 
     LEFT JOIN bugstatus S
     ON S.identifier = R.identifier
     LEFT JOIN priority P
     ON P.identifier = s.identifier

     GROUP BY R.identifier,R.category,S.what,P.what)T
     Where T.RN = 1
     ORDER BY T.identifier;
```

This gives the error:

```js
Error: near "(": syntax error.
```

Answer (score 1):

For each associated table just use a predicate based on a subquery to identify the specific timestamp...

Single letter tokens r, s, and p are defined aliases for tables reports, status and priority respectively

```
Select r.Identifier, r.category,
   coalesce(s.what, 'NA') status,
   coalesce(p.what, 'NA') priority
From reports r
  left join status s
     on s.identifier = r.identifier
        and s.time =
           (Select max(time) from status 
            where identifier = r.identifier)
  left join priority p
     on p.identifier = r.identifier
        and p.time =
           (Select max(time) from priority 
            where identifier = r.identifier);
```

QUESTION: Why did you rename the columns from `Status`, and `priority` to `What`??   You might as well name then `something` or `data`, or `information`.  At least the original names (`status` and `prio`) communicated something..  The word `What` is meaningless.

NOTE. I reversed (undid) the edit for the aliases of `what11` and `what12`,  as these names are e meaningless.

Comment: I receive 
'Error: ambiguous column name: time'

Comment: I see your point regarding the header "what". I didn't define them like that, they were like this in the csv-files. But you're right I could have given more meaningful names to them when creating the SQLite-data base.The query is now running since 4 hours and still didn't finish. I think there must be a query that gets the data faster?@Charles Bretana

Comment: Do the foreign keys have indicies?

Comment: Sorry I can't answer that. The tables are as described in my question. In the reports table the primary key is "identifier". In the other tables a unique identifier would be a combination of "identifier" and "time".@PilotBob

Comment: If you can contact whomever the dbo is, ask them about possible adding indices on `status.time` and `priority.time`.   Also, If it is SQL Server, or if whatever database it is uses clustered indices, I'd make the primary key clustered index on those two tables on the composite of the two fields  (`identifier, time`).(Is this SQL server, or Oracle or MySQL ?? )

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need a correlated subqueries in the select list.

From the hip, something like:

```
Select a.Identifier
,a.Category
,(select process
    from status where status.identifier = a.Identifer order by time desc limit 1) Process
,(select prio
    from priority where priorty.identifier = a.Identifer order by time desc limit 1) prio
From Reports a
```

Comment: @peter: For what does the "a" stand? Is a = reports? Furthermore TOP 1 does not work in SQLite, I read that LIMIT 1 works.
Like this I don't get an error, but the query is still running (I have 300k rows):
'Select reports.identifier
,reports.current_resolution, reports.current_status
,(select what
    from bugstatus where bugstatus.identifier = reports.identifier order by timestamp desc
 LIMIT 1) what
,(select what
    from priority where priority.identifier = reports.identifier order by timestamp desc
 LIMIT 1) what
From reports;`

Comment: Yea, I said it was from the hip, and I used T-SQL, I think your using Sqllite.. so limit 1 seems to be the equivalent. Yes, I meant to alias Reports as A but didn't. Are you saying it works, or it doesn't?

Comment: Yes I'm using SQLite. So, do I need "From reports a" at the end of the query? Is the rest of my proposal with new headers correct? Thanks a lot.@PilotBob

Comment: Yes, that should make reports a... or you could just change it from a to reports in the rest of the query. Your edit looks right I think.

Comment: I edited it to add the alias and use the sqlite limit 1 syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The query is still running. Is it usual that it takes so long? After "...limit 1)" you use "Process" and "prio". Could I also put "what11" and "what22" there respectively is this the new column name?@PilotBob

Comment: I had to stop the query, because it takes too long (more than 90 minutes). I think it should not take so long.@PilotBob

Comment: ah, yea, I don't know sqlite that well. This query in sql server wouldn't run for 90 minutes. You might also try to do subqueries in your from and join on them.

Comment: Do you have a db file with sample data that you can share?

Comment: If you mean with db file a file with the extension .db, created in sqlite, yes I have one. How can I share it? (by the way it's 78 MB).@PilotBob

Answer (score 0):

using Row_number works based on your assumed data

```
select  T.identifier,
        T.category,
        what AS what11,
        what AS what22 from (
     select R.identifier,
     r.category,
     COALESCE(S.what,'NA')what,
     COALESCE(P.what,'NA')what,
     ROW_NUMBER()OVER(partition by R.identifier,r.category ORDER by (select null))RN
     from reports R left join status S
     ON S.identifier = R.identifier
     LEFT JOIN Priority P
     ON P.identifier = s.identifier

     GROUP BY R.identifier,r.category,S.what,P.what)T
     Where T.RN = 1
     ORDER BY T.identifier
```

Comment: For what does T stand for or where is it defined? "ORDER by (select null))RN" For what does RN stand for or where is it defined? Many thanks!

Comment: I have used as Derived Table and T is nothing but Alias name. RN is Row_number and select Null for Ordering Purpose @JohnDavison

Comment: 1) You use small and capital letters for the aliases and tablenames interchangibly. Does that matter? 2) There are no explicit "NA"s in the tables but blanks. Does the code have to be changed? 3) I changed the headers to "what" for the subsequent tables status and priority. Is that an issue if all headers are called "what"?
I get the error: "Error: near "(": syntax error".@mohan111

Comment: NA is nothing but NULL you can change to null and coming to syntax error give column names properly

Comment: Is the edited code correct regarding the new headers in the initial question? And does it matter if the alias is r or R? @mohan111

Comment: it doesn't matter at all and my answer useful to you or not ?? @JohnDavison

Comment: Your code looks good but it's not working unfortunately. I get the error message: "error: near "(" syntax error".

Comment: please post your updated code ..we will work it out @JohnDavison

Comment: I wrote the code under my question. Thanks a lot  for your support.@mohan111

Comment: put t.what for what11 and what22 then it will work @JohnDavison

Comment: I put "t." in front of what for what11 and what22, but now I have a new syntax error near "(". I updated the current code in my question. Where is my mistake?@mohan111